# How to check that mobx observable has subscribers?

Tags: javascript, angular, observer-pattern, mobx

How to check that mobx observable has subscribers?
Or how to get event when observer acquires subscribers?

For example, I have some method: `fetchData()`, and some variable: `@observable responseData`, and I want to run fetchData() only when  responseData has subscribers (consumers like @reaction or @autorun).

And it would be nice if there was a method `isObservableHasSubscribers(observableVar);`

full code example (stack: Angular and Mobx):

```
SomeStore {
    @observable responseData;

    fetchData(){
       if(/* check? */) return; // <- here need some Check ????

       fetchDataFromServer().then((d)=>{
          this.responseData = d;
       })
    }
}

const store = new SomeStore();
let unimportant;

// this is optional consumer (subscriber)...
autorun(() => {
   unimportant = store.responseData;
});

store.fetchData();
```

I want to find an elegant way for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: [MobX uses `hasObservers` under the hood](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/core/observable.ts#L29-L31), so it might be worth opening up an issue and discuss it with the creators if you can't find a way to track it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure its impossible. Observables doesn't hold any state. But Subjects do. In previous RxJs versions there were methods like `subject.hasObservers()`, but in RxJs 5 they are removed. However there is a property that counts observers - `subject.observers.length`.

So what you can do is to turn your Observable into Subject and act on that. Show where your Observable comes from, so maybe I could help further.